# Java service receives email address string in wrong format

Tags: javascript, spring

I am sending email as data for e.g. abc@gmail.com
But Java service receives abc&64;gmail.com and then throws out following as error.

[image]

Project specifications
Front End : Backbone JS, Jquery
Services : Java-> Spring.

I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: You need to decode the value on the `Java` side to convert it back to to your string.

Comment: As mentioned above, you can probably go and decode using something such: org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils, JSoup library or any other library/component you already have in your project dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this problem is about encoding. Try to specify encode in header.

```
$.ajax({
  ....
  contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  ...})
```